# Is a comma required before an interjected “well”?

Tags: commas, interjections

A picture [shared on Instagram](https://instagram.com/p/nLo5Mci8Qt) (original source unknown) contains the following grammar joke:

[image]

> “Well done, well-done, or well, done?”

And, this being a grammar joke, I’d assume it uses correct English. But I can’t help thinking that there should be a comma before the last “well”:

> “Well done, well-done, or, well, done?”

Is the comma optional here? Is it allowed? Or am I entirely misunderstanding the function of the “well” here and it’s not an [interjection](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/well#Interjection)?

(Incidentally, my query implicitly assumes that the comma *before* “or” is an [Oxford comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma) and doesn’t form part of the interjection. Is this correct?)

Comment: (Incidentally, as I understand it “well done” and “well-done” are [completely synonymous](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/well-done), that is they could both refer to either the quality or the cooking time.)

Comment: _Well done_ means _done well_, i.e, a good job of cooking. _Well-done_ in terms of beef means completely cooked, no red meat inside.

Comment: @JohnLawler According to the definition I linked, it can mean either (before looking this up I’d have agreed with you.)

Comment: It can mean either, but if it's being repeated here with _well-done_, it must mean something different. I didn't say it was a very good joke, but it's understandable.

Comment: "You have a choice. I'll call them 'well done', 'well-done', and 'well ... _done_'" The third 'well' is the mitigation marker, not the secondary modifier.

Comment: @Edwin What’s that? It seems the term “mitigation marker” is next to unused (according to Google), and the few references I can find mostly refer to Japanese grammar. At any rate, your rewrite unfortunately doesn’t clear up my understanding of what’s meant.

Comment: When not appearing as a verb, _please_ is a pragmatic marker used to smooth the running of conversation: it is subclass politeness, and often called a 'politeness marker'. Here, in "This burger is, I think you'll agree, well done. This one is well-done. And this one is ... well ... _done_.", _well_ is a pragmatic marker (an ellipsis here conveying a comment on the situation by the speaker); here, it conveys the cook's reluctance to claim anything too wonderful about the third burger....

Comment: The change of _well_'s on which the joke hinges really requires punctuation more drastic than a mere comma in order to be made clear. But that would spoil the flow of the joke in print. It would work better in speech. Possibly.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a comma before the last "well." You're correct that it's an interjection.